# GIMP problem cant install

Tags: 14.04

I need to install GIMP, but every time I hit install I get an error message saying

`This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.`

What can I do?

Comment: It's installed by default on all my 14.04 systems. Any clues in dpkg.log?

Comment: `hit install`? What do you mean? Are you downloading the DEB file from their website? Like @ElderGeek said, it's probably because of a package conflict caused by GIMP already being installed? Have you searched for it in Unity Dash?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise installing via Synaptic Package manager to auto-grab any missing dependencies for your architecture, using terminal is an option but I can't advise it unless you can offer a bit more information. Just run a search in Synaptic for GIMP, it sounds like you'd upgraded to a different lib than is required for the version you are trying to run and will have to allow it to revert or find a merged lib to run the package you are trying to install. If you can offer the source for the GIMP package,what manager or site you are trying to install from and what version and architecture of ubuntu you are using I can offer more specific recommends on which libs to install.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the current installation if any:

`sudo apt-get autoremove gimp gimp-plugin-registry`

Install gimp:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```